# Is there a way I can make zombies run in a certain pattern?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to make an action scene, where zombies run down a hallway. But I need a way to make a zombie run in a straight line in vanilla minecraft. (And possibly wearing armour and a player head!}

Comment: This might help you figure out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a29A6F-M9yo

Answer (score 1):

As far as equipping the zombie with armor, you can spawn it with the `/summon` command (a nice explanation of how to use it can be found [here](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-discussion/recent-updates-and-snapshots/381861-learn-the-summon-command-mobs)).

With regard to getting your zombie to move in a desired direction, I would try spawning a villager in the direction you want the zombie to go. They tend to chase them.

New updates also include invisible blocks called [barriers](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Barrier), so you can limit their paths with those.

Comment: And, the villager will run away, so if you make a single hallway, the villager will run down it with zombies chasing him.

Answer (score 0):

Use a floor with villagers in minecarts under it, and if the minecarts go slow enough, then the zombies will follow the villagers.

Comment: I don't know about this.  There's pathing issues that would probably prevent this.

Comment: I have seen it used in other minigames, such as one pictured in Minecraft for Dummies, so I would think it should work...