# Spawn a villager with a certain effect

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

After seeing [this post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/204293/is-there-a-way-i-can-make-zombies-run-in-a-certain-pattern) about making zombies run in a particular direction/fashion, someone suggested spawning in a Villager to run from the Zombies.

This made me think, can you summon an entity with a certain effect(s) active on spawn? For example, a Villager with Invisibility or a Zombie with Haste?

Comment: Have you tried the `{ActiveEffects:{ ... }}` tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Villager with invisibility:

`/summon Villager ~ ~2 ~ {ActiveEffects:[{‌​Id:14,Amplifier:1,Durati­on:10000000}]}`

Zombie with Speed (haste is mining speed, and zombies can't mine):

`/summon Zombie ~ ~2 ~ {ActiveEffects:[{‌​Id:1,Amplifier:3,Durati­on:10000000}]}`

Additional information can be found in the [/summon command section on the wiki.](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#summon)